# Convert Instagram response device time stamp to readable date time

Tags: python, instagram-api

I'm using [Instagram-API-python](https://github.com/LevPasha/Instagram-API-python) to create an application. I'm getting a JSON response with below value.

```
'device_timestamp': 607873890651
```

I tried to convert this value to readable using python.

```
import time
readable = time.ctime(607873890651)
print(readable)
```

It gives following result and seems it is not correct.

```
Sun Oct  3 16:00:51 21232
```

I'm not much familiar with the **Instagram-API-python**. Please someone can help me to solve this problem.

Comment: At what endpoint you're getting this `device_timestamp`?

Comment: Endpoint means?

Comment: At what URL request you're able to get `device_timestamp`?

Comment: feed/user/%s/?max_id=%s&min_timestamp=%s&rank_token=%s&ranked_content=true'

Comment: Can you share the documentation for API?

Comment: All the details are here [https://github.com/LevPasha/Instagram-API-python] and [https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/08/instagram-python-data-analysis.html]

Comment: I can't find anything related to `device_timestamp` in both of these links. Please provide exact link which mentions `device_timestamp`. Or maybe [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/)?

Answer (score 1):

The data is very likely to be incorrect.

Timestamp is a very standard way to store a date-time. Counting the seconds that passed since January 1st, 1970, also known as the [UNIX Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

I looked for "Instagram 'device_timestamp'" on Google and all the user-provided values made sense, but yours doesn't.

This is probably an error from the database, it happens.

Answer (score 1):

Use the mentioned ctime conversion, but take the 'taken_at' field if available.

Comment: It's better to explain a bit more and add some examples.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `device_timestamp` but use `taken_at` field. Then taken_at need multiply to 1000.

In Java it looks like this

`Date data = new Date(taken_at * 1000);`